# rails+capybara+rspec visit generated url in rspec file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my rspec file i need to visit a generated url.

I have controller, action and object. Is it possible to retrieve the url?

somethings like this:

```
#spec/file.rb
c=postsController
a=edit
p=Post.last

visit url_for(controller: c,action: e,post: p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
c = 'posts'
a = 'edit'
p = Post.last.id
visit (url_for :controller => c, :action => a, :id => p)
```

I've you're using a standard routing pattern, this might work for you too:

```
visit edit_post_url(:id => Post.last.id)
```

Also you may need to create a test post before with something like FactoryGirl :)